# Reparametrising a 1st Fundamental Form to the 1st F.F. of the half-plane model of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions, parametrization

I'm struggling to complete an exercise that gives a reparametrisaton to use to convert one 1st Fundamental form into that of the half-plane model of the hyperbolic plane. I've written out the exercise below followed by my various attempts:

**If we reparametrize the fundamental form $I=du^2+cosh^2(u)dv^2$ by $V=e^vtanh(u)$, $W=\frac{e^v}{cosh(u)}$, then we have $$ I=\frac{dV^2+dW^2}{W^2}$$**

I've tried differentiating $V$ and $W$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ respectively, rearranging for expressions of $du$ and $dv$ to get $du=\frac{dVcosh^2(u)}{e^v}$ and $dv=\frac{dWcosh(u)}{e^v}$ and then substituted these into $I=du^2+cosh^2(u)dv^2$ however I'm left with an extra factor of $cosh^2(u)$.

I also tried finding $\frac{dV}{dv}$ and $\frac{dW}{du}$ and doing the same but was then left with an extra factor of $coth^2(u)$.

Finally I tried adding each of my two expressions for $du$ and $dv$ to get expressions for $du$ and $dv$ in terms of both $dV$ and $dW$ however this gave me an extra factor of $\frac{cosh^4(u)}{4sinh^2(u)}$.

I think there must be an error in my understanding as I've checked my working so many times and can't see an obvious error myself. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, you're not reparametrizing the first fundamental form. You're reparametrizing the *surface* and seeing how the first fundamental form transforms.

Comment: Good to know, I guess this is a classic case of the author of the exercise being a bit lazy with their wording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write out your work. It looks like you're not doing a correct multivariable computation. You should start by writing out $$dV = e^v(\text{sech}^2 u\,du+\tanh u\,dv)$$ and $$dW = e^v\text{sech }u(-\tanh u\,du + dv).$$ Then compute $(dV)^2 + (dW)^2$ as a quadratic differential.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've managed to get it correct now. What's the reasoning for how we compute a multivariable derivative this way? The way I'm reading it we effectively have dV=du(dV/du)+dv(dV/dv), is this the correct formula for it?

Comment: Are we computing the 'Total derivative' as outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative)?

Comment: What you have is correct, except that you should be writing partial derivatives. This is how you do things in multivariable calculus!

Comment: Ah sorry yes, I couldn’t work out how to get the partials formatted in a comment. I think this is one of those things I sort of knew without being explicitly taught it, it’s always been a bit “hand-wavy” as they say (the derivative not the formatting, I mean)

Comment: It's all about the chain rule.